# How to return matched row data by a key value in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to achieve the following by using Apps Script.:

I have a spreadsheet called "Test." In "Test," there are 9 tabs but I want to search only in "sheet1," "sheet2," "sheet3."

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, excluding private or confidential information, and please include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's hard to replicate the copy as it has private information and formulas, which I cannot modify. I have included screenshots and cell locations in the original post for what I would like to achieve. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'll be better if you use inbuilt image hosting (stack.imgur). Try `foundA.push([sh.getName(),r[1],r[2],r[3]]);`

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I just added images in the original post. Is it possible for you to post the full code? (I am not sure where to replace....)

Comment: I ran the script but still the same result. No matched data shows up in the Search Results dialog box...

Comment: There's only one `foundA.push()`. Change it there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed it and ran the script again but it still doesn't return the matched value. The result dialog box shows the same as the last screenshot...

Comment: Could you [edit]  your question to show the latest code? And are you trying to input a course name that is in sheet1?

Comment: I just updated the code. So I want to search by course name. For example in the second screenshot, if I search "Sample course A," return "Sheet1" in Modality, "Ready for final review" in Status, "Team A" in Task Owner, "12/15" in Final Due Date, in the Search Results dialog box. 
However this is just a sample sheet so actual cell locations to be searched are in the original post.
Thank you so much for your advice and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: And yes, when I actually run the script and enter the term, I use a term listed in Sheet1 or Sheet2 or Sheet3.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. The last search term you entered, Was it in sheet1? Coz, there's nothing in your code  specifying where to search like in col b,c or anywhere else... you're only searching ColA(`r[0]`). The inputted course should also be exactly  equal to the name in the sheet,i.e., same space positions, same length, same case(capitals) PS: Notify me using `@`: `@TheMaster`, when you reply.

Comment: @TheMaster: Sorry, I am not very familiar with code...
I am entering a term listed in Sheet1, 2, 3. Specifically Sheet1: Terms to be searched are in A6:A Modality=Sheet1 Status=B6:B Task Owner=C6:C Final Due Date=N6:N

Sheet2: Terms to be searched are in B6:B Modality=Sheet2 Status=C6:C Task Owner=D6:D Final Due Date=R6:R

Sheet3: Terms to be searched are in B6:B Modality=Sheet3 Status=C6:C Task Owner=D6:D Final Due Date=R6:R 5.

Comment: Also can't it be a partial match? I just tried again to enter the exact same course name in search box but it shows nothing in result dialog box.

Comment: You should use `.match()` instead of `==`, if you want a partial match. If you're still unfamiliar with code, I suggest you learn what each line does from the beginning. I see that you already have a working answer below with good reference links. Take time to read and practice each method individually.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You want to search a course name that many appear in any one of three sheets, and then return some relevant course data.

You have described a dynamic ui-based data entry and reporting format. I will leave this for you to develop. This answer used a very simple "search" form on a "search" sheet. There is a cell to enter the search term, and space to display the results.

These images show the before and after:

---

**Blank Search form**

[image: Search Results blank]

---

**Populated Search Results**

[image: Search Results populated]

---

The basics of the script are:

- create a new sheet, name it "search", and create headings as per the image: the search term goes in cell B2; the search results headers go on row 6 (the results will appear on row 7).
- the sheet names that hold course data are listed in an array: `var datasheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"];`
- the script loops through the data sheets: `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(datasheets[d]);`
- the data on each sheet is obtained: `var data = sheet.getRange(startrow,1,LR-startrow+1,5).getValues();`
- using the Javascript [MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, an array of the courses is established: `var courses = data.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]`
- using the Javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method, the script searches for the search term in the courses array: `var result = courses.indexOf(searchdata);`
- when a match is found, the values for course name, sheet name, status, owner and ID are retrieved and pushed onto an array: e.g. `searchresults.push(data[result][3]);// ID`
- the search results are updated with the array results
- there is a check to establish whether the search term was found: `if (resultcounter ==0){`
- if not, then the search results display "No matches": `searchresults.push("No matches"); // message`

---

---

```
function so5868680301() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // define the search sheet
  var sheetname= "search";
  var searchsheet  = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // get the search term
  var searchdata = searchsheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  //Logger.log(searchdata);//DEBUG

  // define the search results output range
  var searchoutput = searchsheet.getRange(7,1,1,5);
  // clear the search results
  searchoutput.clearContent();

  // the sheets to be searched
  var datasheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"]
  //Logger.log(datasheets.length);// DEBUG

  // the start row on the data sheets
  var startrow = 5;
  var resultcounter = 0;


  // loop through the sheets 
  for (var d =0;d<datasheets.length;d++){

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(datasheets[d]);
    //Logger.log(sheet.getName());// DEBUG

    // get the Last row on this sheet
    var LR = sheet.getLastRow();

    // define a range for the sheet
    var data = sheet.getRange(startrow,1,LR-startrow+1,5).getValues();
    //Logger.log(data);//DEBUG

    // get the course list in column A as a separate array
    var courses = data.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]

    // search the courses array for the serachterm
    var result = courses.indexOf(searchdata);

    // if the result is -1, then the sraech term couldn't be found, 
    // otherwise the result is the instance number in the courses array
    if (result !=-1){

      Logger.log(courses); //DEBUG
      Logger.log(result); //DEBUG

      // create an empty array
      var searchresults=[];

      //push the search results onto the array.
      //sheet name
      searchresults.push(courses[result]);// course name
      searchresults.push(sheet.getName());// sheet name
      searchresults.push(data[result][1]);// status
      searchresults.push(data[result][2]);// owner
      searchresults.push(data[result][3]);// ID

      //Logger.log(searchresults);//DEBUG

      searchoutput.setValues([searchresults])
      resultcounter = resultcounter +1;
    }



  }
  if (resultcounter ==0){
    var searchresults=[];
    searchresults.push("No matches"); // message
    searchresults.push(""); 
    searchresults.push(""); 
    searchresults.push(""); 
    searchresults.push(""); 
    //Logger.log(searchresults);//DEBUG
    searchoutput.setValues([searchresults])
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. I will test this and have a look later. Thank you!

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I just tried running but it only works in Sheet1. I guess Sheet 1, 2, 3 have different columns to be searched as mentioned in the original post? What do I need to change to make this work to all the sheets? (I also want final due date, not ID.) @Tedinoz

Comment: The names of the sheets are in this line `var datasheets = ["Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3"]`; it does loop (I've tested it). Just check that _your_ sheets are spelled like this, or edit as appropriate. **Unless** you're saying that the search term could be found on more than one sheet?? Final due date...if that is in Column J then swap this for the ID: `searchresults.push(data[result][9]);// Final Due Date`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The search term is unique but the thing is cell locations for the results to be pulled are different from each sheet.

Sheet1: Search term is located in A6:A, Status is located in B6:B Task Owner is located in C6:C Final Due Date is located in N6:N.

Sheet2: Search term in B6:B Status=C6:C Task Owner=D6:D Final Due Date=R6:R

Sheet3: Search term in B6:B Modality=Sheet3 Status=C6:C Task Owner=D6:D Final Due Date=R6:R 5.
That could be why it doesn't work in Sheet2 and 3. @Tedinoz

Comment: This information should be in your question. You chose not to share your spreadsheet but shared ONE screenshot of ONE sheet. Would you please edit your question to show the layout on the other two sheets.